# Dynamic memory allocation in c using malloc

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, pointer-arithmetic

Allocated a `50*sizeof(int)` of dynamic memory using `malloc`. As I read in some document the immediately below element should be a size of allocated memory using `malloc` (In my case it is 200 bytes). But when i executed this below code, got 209 instead 200!

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<malloc.h>
    int main()
    {
        int *p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*50);

        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            scanf("%d", &p[i]);

        for(i = -1; i < 5; i++)
            printf(" %d ", *((int *)(p+i)));
        free(p);
    }
```

Can somebody help whats wrong?

Comment: Where in your code do you get 209?

Comment: Output of first element printed from this snippet--->            for(i=-1;i<5;i++)
            printf(" %d ",*((int *)(p+i)));

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: How malloc does its housekeeping is implementation dependent. Probably some implementation will indeed store the net allocated size just before the first element, but that's up to the authors of the library. What implementation of malloc are you using?

Comment: @Sourav But Didn't solve my problem

Comment: @fvu Found this from man page
       "This page is part of release 3.22 of the Linux man-pages project."

Comment: @VijaySB Interesting. Can you quote the part of that man page that says this? I have found that exact man page of malloc and it doesn't talk about this (because documenting something so implementation specific would be somewhere between irresponsible and insane).

Comment: @VijaySB that's why that is a comment,not an answer. A ful answer is given below, anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undefined behavior. You're accessing memory that is outside the region that `malloc()` returned and this is not valid.

If it was valid in some context, that was an implementation-specific extension and not something you can depend on or do in the general case.

Also, please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C. The printing could just be:

```
printf(" %d ", p[i]);
```

the asterisk and cast that you added are not necessary, just use array indexing.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the first iteration of

```
for(i=-1;i<5;i++)
        printf(" %d ",*((int *)(p+i)));
```

here, the index `-1` refers to an invalid memory location and attempt to access that invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, There is no *wrap-around* for array indexing in C, it's simple pointer arithmetic and as soon as you point outside the allocated memory region, you hit UB.

That said,

- `malloc.h` is depreacted and very linux specific, better use `stdlib.h` to get the forward definition of `malloc()`.
- [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: If i'm accessing a invalid memory location every time i execute the code, i should get the garbage value right? I'm getting same value every-time

Answer (score 1):

Tell me the document where you have seen written that the elemnt below malloc()'s return address telles the size of malloc(). I have just read man-page of malloc() but I couldn't find and have never heard of it before. I think you're confused. There's no way to find out the size of dynamically allocated memory unless you keep it.

Comment: "The Linux Programming Interface.pdf" by Michael Kerrisk 
When malloc() allocates the block, it allocates
extra bytes to hold an integer containing the size of the block. This integer is
located at the beginning of the block; the address actually returned to the caller
points to the location just past this length value,

Comment: Vijay S B, I learned more about malloc() thanks to your comment. Now I understand how free() works without telling the size of dinymically allocated by malloc(), and I raised a question that the size of integer must be a long integer if it works on 64bit OS.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the book "The Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk.

Comment: By the way there's no need to store the length before, or after the allocated memory.  You can simply store it elsewhere.  So be careful, as **this is a real case of undefined behaviour**.